# join dataframes with the same index into excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm reading a csv and I'm adding a dataframe to it, but I need you to follow the index consecutively, do you know any way to do it?
Attached the code

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("test3.csv")

document = {'price': price, 'get_by': get_by, 'name': name, 'company': company, 'link': link, "date":date,"search_position": search_position } 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(document) 

df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
df3.to_csv('test3.csv', index=False)
```

As a result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnuCH.png)

df1 and df2 samples

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjfi7.png)

Comment: Please update your post with a sample of `df1` and `df2`. For example with `print(df1.head(10))`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that df1 has a numbering column (the first column) while df2 doesn't.

The solution is to drop the first column in df1 and use

```
df3.to_csv('test3.csv', index=True)
```

Comment: yep, i tried to dop it but i  couldnt do it, i updated my post with samples i hope that you can see the changes

Comment: i didnt resolve this problem any idea?

Comment: try dropping the first column by ```df.drop(columns='<name_of_the_first_column'>, inplace=True)```